# What is the openstreetmap route network structure

Tags: routes, openstreetmap, traffic

I'm trying to run my own algorithm for routing.
I understand that what we call 'links' in traffic are not defined explicitly in OSM. In OSM, a way has common nodes with other ways. In links' terms, there should not be any way that has a common node with another way, unless it is either the start point or the endpoint. In other words, ways are split into multiple links.

I'm also aware that ways are selected according to their tags suitable for different vehicle types.

Now my question is, how others are doing the routing in OSM? I don't actually need to know where the link for the source code of some algorithm is, but to know **if they are virtually doing the link structure I mentioned or not**.

And if the answer to the question is no, then I will create my own link structure by splitting those ways for myself.

Thank you.

p.s. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService is the least useful explanation for the structure.

Comment: I'm not sure if this link is what i'm looking for, but it seems everyone create their own graph data. [How to route on OSM without using any already released routing engine?][1] [1]:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32234/how-to-route-on-osm-without-using-any-already-released-routing-engine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, people like myself who have implemented a routing algorithm using OpenStreetMap data have done what you described: create a graph structure containing nodes for points shared by more than one road, and arcs for the parts of the roads connecting the nodes.

It works very well. OSM data is not perfect, but the intention and definition of the data is that if two roads share a node, they connect, so when the data has been correctly entered and marked up, routing works fine.